# HashMap to String error message

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display files on my phone from firebase, but in my log cat I get the error failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String.

I am able to upload the files into firebase, just cannot seem to retrieve the files once they have been uploaded.

I think it may be something to do with this line

String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

```
public class MyRecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_recycler_view);

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override // indivivdual items at the db ref
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String fileName = dataSnapshot.getKey(); //returns file name
            String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); //returns url for file name

            ((MyAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).update(fileName,url);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyRecyclerViewActivity.this));

    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(recyclerView,MyRecyclerViewActivity.this, new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<String>());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read your *entire* database at once.  Is this what you intended?  Here, you are getting a reference to the root of your database:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Then, you attach a listener to it:

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(...);
```

The listener is going to get invoked with a DataSnapshot of the entire contents of your database, which is probably not just a String, as you are expected.  If the root of your database includes child nodes, you will get a HashMap of their keys and values.

Consider instead locating the string you're looking for by specifying its path in a DatabaseReference object.

Comment: I need to get access to the the database to access all the files which are stored in it. So, when a user uses the app, they are able to search through all the available files and select which one they want to retrieve.

Comment: You're going to have to deal with that HashMap, then.

Comment: How would I be able to locate a specific path in a DatabaseReference object? As I have stored all the files in one folder within the database, so maybe I can try to access via that?

Comment: You're going outside the scope of your original question.  I'd suggest formulating a new question that explains what your current issue is.  It's not just an issue with HashMap and String - it's something more fundamentally basic abut how the client APIs work.  If you haven't read the documentation, follow along with that first: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a read at that. Its because thats what the error says about HashMap and String.